# Manipulating a dataframe with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':list('abc'),
                   'col2':list('xyz'),
                   'col3':[10,20,30]})

print (df)
  col1 col2  col3
0    a    x    10
1    b    y    20
2    c    z    30
```

and i want to create a dataframe like this :

```
  col1 col2  col3
0    a    x    10
1    a    y    20
2    a    z    30
3    b    x    10
4    b    y    20
5    b    z    30
6    c    x    10
7    c    y    20
8    c    z    30
```

w.r.t first column which in this case is a unique identifier for the problem.
How to approach this problem?

Comment: With melt the desired objective is not fulfilled.
Kindly look at the final desired output.

Comment: Is there any algorithm behind this? If not, write static output and you're done

Comment: @nOObda - Please check answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need `list comprehension` with zip second and third column:

```
from  itertools import product

L = [[i, *j] for i, j in product(df['col1'], zip(df['col2'], df['col3']))]
df = pd.DataFrame(L, columns=['col1','col2','col3'])
print (df)
  col1 col2  col3
0    a    x    10
1    a    y    20
2    a    z    30
3    b    x    10
4    b    y    20
5    b    z    30
6    c    x    10
7    c    y    20
8    c    z    30
```